# Add data in resource file(.resx) on the click of button

Tags: c#, winforms, resx

I want to add data in resource file on the click of button in windows form.
I've a windows form with 3 text boxes -

text_box1: Name
text_box2: Value
text_box3: Comments
and a button named as `Save`.

I am able to save data in the resource file but not in that way in which I want.   It is saving in every value in next row but I want Name comes under Name column, value should came under column, same as for comment.

my code for button click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myMethod.Create(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);          
}
```

Code for writing data in resource file:

```
public class myMethod
{
    public static void Create(string myName, string myValue, string myComment)
    {

        ResXResourceWriter resxWriter;
        try
        {
            resxWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(@"D:\Validator_Tool\resx\resx\myres.resx");
            resxWriter.AddResource("Name", myName);
            resxWriter.AddResource("Value",myValue);
            resxWriter.AddResource("Comment", myComment);
            resxWriter.Close();

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException caught)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Source: " + caught.Source + " Message: " + caught.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to append these 3 value in a row not in new row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **[`ResXDataNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxdatanode.aspx)**.

Name and value can be passed to one of its constructor:

```
public ResXDataNode(string name, object value)
```

and comment can be set through the property `Comment`.

It is convenient to use object initializer in this case:

```
public static void Create(string myName, string myValue, string myComment)
{
    ResXResourceWriter resxWriter;
    try
    {
        resxWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(@"D:\Validator_Tool\resx\resx\myres.resx");

        // --- Use this if it looks more readable and convenient ---
        // var node = new ResXDataNode(myName, myValue);
        // node.Comment = myComment;
        // resxWriter.AddResource(node);

        resxWriter.AddResource(new ResXDataNode(myName, myValue)   
        {
            Comment = myComment
        });

        resxWriter.Close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException caught)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Source: " + caught.Source + " Message: " + caught.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev, I need one more help to you that whenever I pushing/append data in resx file it overwrite my existing data so, could you please tell me what should I do in this case ?

Comment: @VIVEKJAIN You need to use `ResXResourceReader` to read all resources, store it in a `List` or something similar, append your `ResXDataNode`, and save it using `ResXResourceWriter`. By the way, setting `UseResXDataNodes` to true can make it simpler. Try it :)